# How to check value exist in table use javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select name="product">
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>

<table id="ListProduct">
<tr data-id="1"><td>A</td></tr>
<tr data-id="4"><td>D</td></tr>
<tr data-id="5"><td>E</td></tr>
<tr data-id="6"><td>F</td></tr>
<tr data-id="7"><td>G</td></tr>
</table>
```

And my javascript:

```
$('select[name=product]').on('change', function(){
   var pid = $('select[name=product]').val();
   var table = $('#ListProduct');
   var check_value = $(table).find("tr").data('id').eq(pid);
   if(check_value) alert("ID exist") else alert("Not exist");
});
```

When I select value=1, bring error. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/1bnkfb06/

```
$('select[name=product]').on('change', function(){
   var pid = $(this).val();
   var table = $('#ListProduct');
   var check_value = $(table).find("tr").data('id');

   if(check_value == pid) {
       console.log("ID exist") 
   }
       else {
           console.log("Not exist");
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new option to ensure that the ID for A can also be found

```js
$('select[name=product]').on('change', function(){
   var pid = $(this).val();
   var table = $('#ListProduct');
   var check_value = $(table).find("tr").data('id');
   (check_value == pid)?alert('ID exists'):alert('ID does not exist');//check if id exists
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="product">
    <option>select</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select>

<table id="ListProduct">
<tr data-id="1"><td>A</td></tr>
<tr data-id="4"><td>D</td></tr>
<tr data-id="5"><td>E</td></tr>
<tr data-id="6"><td>F</td></tr>
<tr data-id="7"><td>G</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error as `.data('id')` in your code returns an integer which doesn't have `.eq` method. `.eq` is a method of the jQuery object.

Also note that `.data` as getter returns value of the first element in the collection. You should either iterate through the `tr` collection and filter the matching elements or use the power of the jQuery selector engine:

```
$('select[name=product]').on('change', function() {
   var $tr = $('#ListProduct tr[data-id="'+ this.value +'"]');

   if ( $tr.length ) {
      alert("ID exist");
   } else { 
      alert("Not exist");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check wether the value of product matches the data id in listproduct like this. http://jsfiddle.net/38e2h5ao/

```
$('select[name=product]').on('change', function () {
    var pid = $('select[name=product]').val();
    var table = $('#ListProduct');
    var exist;
    $(table).find("tr").each(function () {
        var check_value = $(this).data('id');
        if (check_value == pid) {
            exist = true;
        }
    });

    if (exist) alert("ID exist");
    else alert("Not exist");
});
```